# Javascript starts with or contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get some help on some JavaScript we are trying to post accross multiple landing pages.  We are sending values to hidden fields on a button click 'lp-pom-button-3'.

However, the ID changes depending on the page, but will always have the format 'lp-pom-button-' with the number potentially changing depending on the page.  Is there a function similar to 'like' in SQL, or saying any button that starts with or contains 'lp-pom-button-" for this to be triggered on? Thanks for you help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-3').addEventListener(
'click', function(event) {
  ga(function() { 
    var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
    var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    document.getElementById('GACLIENTID').value = clientId;
    var userId = tracker.get('userId'); 
    document.getElementById('GAUSERID').value = userId; 
  });
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[id^=lp-pom-button]").forEach(function() {... })` - same selector can be used in jQuery

Comment: avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: @dlatikay no. The question was a duplicate so I posted a suggestion while looking for a dupe to avoid answers - Titue did not see my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css selector for attribute value contains.

```
[id*="lp-pom-button-"]
```

or attribute value starts with:

```
[id^="lp-pom-button-"]
```

In vanilla javascript you can access elements using css selector with `querySelector` or for getting a list of elements `querySelectorAll`.

Here is an example:

```
document.querySelector('[id^="lp-pom-button-"]');
```

And [HERE](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) is a list of all the browsers and browsers version that support this function.

Comment: The OP is using `getElementById`. May want to be specific about the method you are invoking here.

Comment: See comment under question